# Spearman's Correction for Attenuation - What type of reliability?

Tags: correlation, reliability

I am trying to correct a correlation coefficient with Spearman's disattenuation formula:

**rx'y' = rxy/sqrt(rxx*ryy)**

The equation is pretty straightforward, however, the literature always talks about *reliability* without specifying what type of reliability to use. That is, should one use external measures of reliability (e.g. test-retest, inter-rater) or internal measures of reliability (e.g. Cronbach's alpha) to quantify the measurement error of an instrument?

Comment: What's 'the literature'? Which field are we on about here?

Comment: @jcken - See for instance: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/test.12087

Comment: Isn't reliability a concept that is obtained using different kinds of formulas, depending on the context of the analysis or sample of the data? Meaning: for the attenuation correction formula it doesn't matter how you obtained reliability. The real question is, did you use the best way to measure reliability.